# how to get universal axis with grid.extra and do call in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I applied  a for loop in R and generated  graphs using do call and grid arrange

It looks similar to this output here which is what I want

[How do I arrange a variable list of plots using grid.arrange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706753/how-do-i-arrange-a-variable-list-of-plots-using-grid-arrange)

```
p1 <- c(p,list(nrow=4,ncol=2)) 
do.call(grid.arrange,p1, right = "people", bottom = "XX", top="Regression")
```

However, I want to tidy the graph and I would like a universal y and x-axis labels with one title but after using the codes above I got error "unused arguments (right = "people", bottom = "XX", top = "Regression")

Any ideas on to sort this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?do.call`

> **Usage**
>
> do.call(what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame())
>
> **Arguments**
>
> **what**    either a function or a non-empty character string naming the function to be called.
>   **args**    a list of arguments to the function call. The names attribute of args gives the argument names.
>   **quote** a logical value indicating whether to quote the arguments.
>   **envir** an environment within which to evaluate the call. This will be most useful if what is a character string and the arguments are symbols or quoted expressions.

You just need to amend your argument list to include the other parameters. I changed the y axis to be on the left.

```
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

p <- list(plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot) 

args <- c(p, list(nrow = 4,ncol = 2, left = "people", bottom = "XX", top = "Regression")) 

do.call(grid.arrange, args)
```

[image]

or what @baptiste suggests (I swear I'm going to vote for a !summon command on SO for him)

`grid.arrange(grobs = p, nrow = 4,ncol = 2, left = "people", bottom = "XX", top = "Regression")`

Comment: Alternatively, grid.arrange has a grobs argument, no need for do.call.