# My for loop in r stops at the first iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe in r and I want to provide the boxplot of each integer variable. I have 34 variables so it's useless to do them manually, thus I opted for a for loop but it only returns the first boxplot of the first variable. 
Here's the code I used:

```
for (i in 1:34) {
  if (class(data[,i])== "integer") {
    return(boxplot(data[,i])) 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code stops, because `return` is called.

Sadly, in R you cannot store base plots in a variable without using [additional libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/9291522). But if you use **ggplot2** for creating your boxplots, you can store them into a list:

```r
plots <- list()
a <- 1
for (i in 1:34) {
  if (class(data[,i]) == "integer") {
    plots[[a]] <- boxplot(data[,i])) 
    a <- a + 1
  } 
}
```

Subsequently, you can plot them all together in a grid by using `grid.arrange` from ggplot2. The following code should do the trick (*big thanks to [Josh O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10706828/9291522)*):

```r
library(gridExtra)

n <- length(plots)
nCol <- floor(sqrt(n))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots, ncol=nCol))
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on [georg_un](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9291522/georg-un)'s answer:

Calling `return()` will stop execution of all cycles.

Consider this example:

```
for (i in 1:500) {

  for (y in 1000:1) {

      cat(paste("big", i, "small", y))

      return("the end is nigh!")
  }

}
```

This will not print 500 000 items (500x big cycle, 1000x small cycle) but only one.
The `return()` will stop everything...

Return is normally not used in context of for cycles, but for early termination of  functions.