# Automatically assemble plots for patchwork from a list of ggplots

Tags: r, tidyverse, patchwork

I'm trying to workout a function (without any success) that will automatically assemble a list of ggplots plots with `patchwork`.

The function would take in the following inputs:

- no_of_rows
- no_of_cols
- master_list_with_plots

With thee inputs the function should automatically structure the plots. I have provided an example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
  
p1 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(mpg))
p2 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(cyl))
p3 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(disp))
p4 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(hp))
p5 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(drat))                                   
p6 <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(wt))

plot_list <- list(mpg  = p1,
                  cyl  = p2,
                  disp = p3,
                  hp   = p4,
                  drat = p5,
                  wt   = p6)

# Function inputs
no_of_rows = 2
no_of_col2 = 3
master_list_with_plots = org_plot
    
#Function output would be org_plot below
org_plot <- plot_list[["mpg"]] + plot_list[["cyl"]] + plot_list[["disp"]] + 
            plot_list[["hp"]]  + plot_list[["drat"]] + plot_list[["wt"]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `patchwork::wrap_plots(plot_list, no_of_rows, no_of_col2)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706753/how-do-i-arrange-a-variable-list-of-plots-using-grid-arrange/51352933#51352933

Answer (score 14):

You can put `patchwork::wrap_plots` in a function :

```
plot_a_list <- function(master_list_with_plots, no_of_rows, no_of_cols) {

  patchwork::wrap_plots(master_list_with_plots, 
                        nrow = no_of_rows, ncol = no_of_cols)
}

plot_a_list(plot_list, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

If it is a simple grid of plots you are looking for, try have a look at the package `gridExtra` (functions like `gridExtra::grid.arrange`), or a more easy wrapper of this function for ggplots called `ggpubr::ggarange`. Given your `plot_list` object, you can try:

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

`byrow = TRUE` is the default. Setting this to `FALSE` will arrange your plot list by columns.